# update a line dynamically using d3 makes the line move back and forth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have real time data which I need to show in a line chart. So I am updating the path using  (doing this for every second)

```
svg.select(".strream").data([streamData]).interrupt().transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .ease("linear").attr("d", StepAfterLine)
```

This makes my graph moving smoother, but I want to delete the old data from the array. So I was comparing the times and deleting the old data, surprisingly it makes my chart moving back and forth. Can any one please help me why the lines are moving differently if I remove old data from an array?

Comment: Without knowing the details of your code, this is most likely an effect of data joins and the update pattern. You may want to have a look at [*General Update Pattern*](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), [*Thinking with Joins*](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/), and [*How Selections Work*](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) to get a grasp of what's going on.

Comment: And this one too can help http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html

Answer (score 0):

I got answer to my question. In the above code I was animating line. Instead apply animation  to transform.

```
svg.select(".strream").data([strreamDataArray])
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,10)")
        .attr("d", realStepAfterLine)
        .interrupt().transition().ease("linear")
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("transform", "translate(xscale(0))");
```